# Elegantly return value(s) matching criteria from an array of nested hashes - in one line

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, data-structures

I have been searching for a solution to this issue for a couple of days now, and I'm hoping someone can help out.  Given this data structure:

```
'foo' => {
  'bar' => [
    {
      'baz' => {'faz' => '1.2.3'},
      'name' => 'name1'
    },
    {
      'baz' => {'faz' => '4.5.6'},
      'name' => 'name2'
    },
    {
      'baz' => {'faz' => '7.8.9'},
      'name' => 'name3'
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find the value of 'faz' that begins with a '4.', without using each.  I have to use the '4.' value as a key for a hash I will create while looping over 'bar' (which obviously I can't do if I don't yet know the value of '4.'), and I don't want to loop twice.

Ideally, there would be an elegant one-line solution to return the value '4.5.6' to me.

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990332/return-single-key-from-nested-hash-in-ruby), but it doesn't address the full complexity of this data structure, and the only answer given for it is too verbose; the looping-twice solution is more readable. I'm using Ruby 2.3 on Rails 4 and don't have the ability to upgrade. Are there any Ruby gurus out there who can guide me?

Comment: You need an open brace before `foo`. I’m guessing you also want `foo` and `bar` to be literals (e.g., `’foo’` and `’bar’`). While you’re at it, assign the hash to a variable (e.g., `h = { ‘foo’=>...}`), so that readers can refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Comment: `h['foo']['bar'].find { |hh| hh['baz']['faz'].start_with? '4.' }['baz']['faz']`?  Naah!

Comment: Why the Rails tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-select) to filter results.

```
data = {'foo' => {'bar' => [{'baz' => {'faz' => '1.2.3'}, 'name' => 'name1'}, {'baz' => {'faz' => '4.5.6'}, 'name' => 'name2'}, {'baz' => {'faz' => '7.8.9'}, 'name' => 'name3'}]}}

data.dig('foo', 'bar').select { |obj| obj.dig('baz', 'faz').slice(0) == '4' }
#=> [{"baz"=>{"faz"=>"4.5.6"}, "name"=>"name2"}]

# or if you prefer the square bracket style
data['foo']['bar'].select { |obj| obj['baz']['faz'][0] == '4' }
```

The answer assumes that every element inside the `bar` array has the nested attributes `baz -> faz`.

If you only expect one result you can use [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) instead.

Comment: Why have you used `dig`, rather than `data['foo']['bar']` and `obj['baz']['faz']`? The OP has not suggested, in words or the example, that the nested keys may not be present. If a key that is supposed to be there is missing `dig` would merrily return `nil`, masking the omission. In that case we would want an exception to be raised.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I prefer `dig` with multiple arguments over chaining `[]` calls, only for style. Presence is still required since `select` or `slice` will only work when the correct object is returned. But you could replace `data.dig('foo', 'bar')` with `data['foo']['bar']` if you prefer the look of that. Updated the answer with the alternative.

Comment: Suppose `'baz' => {'faz' => '4.5.6'}` had been mistakenly written `'bazz' => {'faz' => '4.5.6'}` then by using `dig` (when looking for `4`) an empty array would have been returned, which may have been a possible outcome. Had `'baz'` and `'faz'` been used explicitly, an exception would be raised, which would be helpful. There are of course other examples of errors that are missed and the use of `dig` causes a non-empty, but erroneous, array to be returned.